# Python - How to store a Search Result (list) in a variable?

Tags: python

I am having trouble storing a list in a variable. I am new to python so I don't know if this is the way to do it. In the example below, I am searching for a string in textfiles in a certain directory. I like to store the search results in a variable.

**I have this:**

```
import os.path
import glob

rootDir = '/Volumes/audio/TRANSCRIBE/OUT'

os.chdir( rootDir )
for files in glob.glob( "*.txt" ):
    with open(files) as f:
        contents = f.read()
    if (re.search(r'\b'+ re.escape(searchPhrase) + r'\b', contents, re.IGNORECASE)):
        print( files )
```

**The 'Search Result' Output:**

```
FW_A01_2020-12-01_1812_C0003.txt
FW_A01_2020-12-01_1908_C0010.txt
FW_A01_2020-12-01_2204_C0032.txt
FW_A01_2020-12-09_0350_C0225.txt
FW_A01_2020-12-09_0352_C0226.txt
FW_A01_2020-12-09_0353_C0227.txt
FW_A01_2020-12-09_0353_C0228.txt
```

**My Question:** How do I store this search result in a variable?

**I tried this:**

```
searchResult = files
```

But that does not work.

Comment: Note: `files` may be better named to `filename`.

Comment: For your question: create an empty list variable `filenames = []` above the for-loop, then use `filenames.append(filename)` inside the if-clause (using my above suggestion).

Comment: It may be worth your while going through the [tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html), which deals with lists and appending to them fairly early on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an empty list that you append each new result like this:

```
results = []
for files in glob.glob( "*.txt" ):
    with open(files) as f:
        contents = f.read()
    if (re.search(r'\b'+ re.escape(searchPhrase) + r'\b', contents, re.IGNORECASE)):
        results.append(files)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

Make an array/list, and add them to the list with .append()

```
import os.path
import glob

results = []
rootDir = '/Volumes/audio/TRANSCRIBE/OUT'

os.chdir( rootDir )
for files in glob.glob( "*.txt" ):
    with open(files) as f:
        contents = f.read()
    if (re.search(r'\b'+ re.escape(searchPhrase) + r'\b', contents, re.IGNORECASE)):
        results.append(files)
        print( files )
```